# Calling WCF service through https

Tags: silverlight, wcf, .net-2.0, https, cross-domain

I have recently implemented SSL on a WCF service. I deployed it on a IIS server, which is on another machine of the network (my developer machine doesn't have IIS, so i can't test locally). Whenever i try to call the WCF service, i'm having the error:

"CommunicationException... failed... ask for cross-domain policy... which accept SOAP http header..." sure, you know what i'm talking about.

I skimmed through all forums, but i got no answer. The SSL certificate is a self-signed one. I'm able to view the wsdl of my deployed service, so i think the certificate config is ok.

My **cross-domain file** (which has exactly the **same** content than my **clientaccesspolicy** file):
(Problem with displaying my file in the forum)

```
--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
->access-policy>
->cross-domain-access>
    ->policy>

        <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
            <domain uri="https://*"/>
            <domain uri="http://*" />
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
        </grant-to>
    </policy>
</cross-domain-access>
/access-policy>
```

Comment: Where is your clientaccesspolicy located?  Also, try using webdevhelper or fiddler to log requests, then post the failing request for the clientaccesspolicy.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is enabled for both my web site and my web service, which are deployed on separate ports. I have tested the web service call on my local machine, using "http://localhost:port/TestPage.aspx" and "https://IISserverName:port/TestPage.aspx", but none is working.